# Word Fillable Form with Time Field

Tags: forms, ms-word

Trying to make a fillable form

That has a time input

that is in a format like i.e 11:00 AM

and that's the only way you can put the time in

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple formfield (Developer|Controls|Legacy Tools>Text Form Field), then accessing its properties and setting the Type to 'Date' and the Date Format to 'h:mm am/pm'.

Do note that formfields only work with the 'Filling in forms' editing restrictions applied; they should also not be used in a document containing content controls, as the two weren't designed to work together and trying to use them that way can cause problems.